# Hold Subroutine response and set to variable in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

thesub("hello");

sub thesub {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = shift;
   return $self;

}
my $testvar = thesub();

print $testvar;
```

$testvar print nothing, **I want to print  hello.**
I have intent to change thesub() to \&thesub, but not work.

I read that In Perl, scalar variables cannot hold subroutines directly.

How can I fixed this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain more of what you are trying to do. Why are you using `$class` and returning `$self`? Why are you shifting two items off the stack, and only passing a single parameter in? An immediate fix: try `return $class` instead of `return $self`

Comment: *"I read that In Perl, scalar variables cannot hold subroutines directly."* Yes, they can, scalars can hold references to subroutines, see [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). Please explain why you would want to do so in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have package, so I'll assume you don't want to use a class,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

sub thesub {
    state $stored;

    $stored = shift if @_;
    return $stored;
}

thesub("hello");
print thesub();
```

Comment: Hi @Сухой27, I want to **used this in package**, in main script I have, 

`use Mymodule;`
`Mymodule::thesub("hello from main script\n");`


`package Mymodule;`
..........

I get this error: 

**Use of uninitialized value $testvar in print line**

can you please suggest me how to fixed ?

Comment: How to send value from main script to that function without get undef value return ?

Comment: @Imylor: You description is unclear and it's a bad idea to try and share code in comments. Please ask a new question, including this information.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing one parameter into `thesub()`, but it expects two. So "hello" ends up in `$class` and `$self` ends up containing nothing (or, more precisely, `undef`). The easiest fix is to remove the line which assigns to `$class`. But I'm not sure if that's the best fix as I'm pretty unclear on what you're actually trying to do here.

The variable names (`$class`, `$self`) make me think you're reading a tutorial about object-oriented programming. But there's no OO going on here.

Also, I can't think of a situation in OO Perl where you'd pass both `$class` and `$self` to a methd.

Comment: *"Also, I can't think of a situation in OO Perl where you'd pass both $class and $self to a method"* Maybe `Class->clone($class_ob)`?

Comment: @Borodin: I didn't claim to be thinking particularly **hard* :-)