# Program unexpectedly reports "Use of uninitialized value"

Tags: perl, module, subroutine, scalar

This is with regard to my previous question
[*Hold Subroutine response and set to variable in Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791034/hold-subroutine-response-and-set-to-variable-in-perl)

The statement `Module::thesub("hello")`
worked in `Module.pm` but fails if I move it to `main.pl`

#### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Module;

Module::thesub("hello");
```

#### Module.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Module;

sub thesub {
    state $stored;

    $stored = shift if @_;
    return $stored;
}

my $testvar = thesub();

print $testvar;

1;
```

I get this error

> Use of uninitialized value `$testvar`

which means the variable `$testvar` has no value.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Statements in a module run when the module is loaded, at `use Module;`.  At that time `thesub()` still wasn't called with an argument and `$stored` in it is undefined. So that is what `$testvar` gets when it's assigned and the warning is emitted when it's printed.

The `$testvar` can be used in main

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module;

Module::thesub("hello");

my $testvar = Module::thesub();
```

even though I am not sure from the question what the purpose of this is.

Remove the assignment and print of `$testvar` from the module. Note that you'll also need `use feature 'state';` at the beginning of the module, to enable the [feature pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

---

A few comments on the module you show

- No need for `#!/usr/bin/perl`, as a module is generally not meant to be run
- The `package Module;` is commonly the first line
- While what you have works, consider making symbols from the module available to the calling code, so that it can import them and simply say `thesub()`.  A common way is

  ```
  package Module;

  use warnings;
  use strict;

  use Exporter qw(import);
  our @EXPORT_OK = qw(thesub);

  sub thesub { ... }

  1;
  ```

  and in the main

  ```
  use Module qw(thesub);

  thesub("hello");
  ```

  See [Exporter](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for starters and search SO, where there are great many posts on this.